# web3.py - Python dtype for contract function with int256[x]

Tags: solidity, abi, web3.py, data-types

Say I have this example contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract SEexample {

    int256[3] thing;
    uint8 internal i=0;

    function submit(int256[3] bids,int256[3] prefs) public returns (int256[3]){
            for (i=0;i<3;i++){
                thing[i] = bids[i] + prefs[i];
            }
        return thing;
    }
}
```

Giving this abi:

```
[
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "bids",
                "type": "int256[3]"
            },
            {
                "name": "prefs",
                "type": "int256[3]"
            }
        ],
        "name": "submit",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "int256[3]"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

And I deploy using web3.py:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, IPCProvider
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))   //(testrpc)
tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': w3nce.eth.accounts[0], 'gas': 10000000})
tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']
contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi, ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract)
```

**How do I instruct python to meet the int256[13] that the function requires?**

I've tried variations on:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.ones((3,),dtype=int)
b=np.ones((3,),dtype=int)
x=contract_instance.submit(a,b, transact={'from': w3.eth.accounts[1]})
```

also with `a.tobytes()`, `b.tobytes()`

Results in :

```
raise ValueError("No matching functions found")
```

ValueError: No matching functions found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
x=contract_instance.submit(a.tolist(),b.tolist(), transact={'from': w3.eth.accounts[1]})
```